# Can the Klingon Mind-sifter be used to alter a person's memories?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery

The Klingon [Mind-scanner](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Mind_scanner), sometimes called [Mind-sifter](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Mind-sifter), sometimes called mind-ripper - is an interrogation tool. We see this used on Spock in the TOS Episode [S1:E27](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Errand_of_Mercy_(episode)) *Errand of Mercy*.

We know that the Star Trek Universe has technology called a [Thought-maker](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Thought_maker) from the TNG Episode [S1:E9](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Battle_(episode)) The Battle.

We know a little of Klingon interrogation from Discovery [S1:E4](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Butcher%27s_Knife_Cares_Not_for_the_Lamb%27s_Cry_(episode)) *The Butcher's Knife Cares Not for the Lamb's Cry*.

My question is: **Can the Klingon Mind-sifter be used to alter a person's memories?**

Comment: Well, *alter* could also be interpreted to mean *the removal of* and extended use of the 'mind sifter' leaves the subject in a state described as *'there would be very little of your mind left, Captain'*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not canonically on screen, though not denied either, but in licensed fiction from as early as the story 'Mind-sifter' [in Star Trek: The New Voyages (1976) the first licensed short story collection] by Shirley S. Maiewski

I no longer own a copy, but from memory, Kirk's memories were muddled and dimmed (which is altered to a degree) but short of building false memories of any detail.

It was adapted for the fan Phase II project here, with the original author's agreement, and the full script is here: https://www.fanfiction.net/s/6155771/1/MindSifter. This confirms it could block memories, by inducing intolerable pain when the subject tries to access them, but it is not shown as being capable of creating new ones.

Comment: It sounds like this is the answer. Are you able to add an excerpt from the story showing how someone's memories were altered? The best description of the story I found was in this Amazon review. https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/RBLVI507VCCTK/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=0553246364